# protobuf-net skips a member (of Interface type) from base class

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a `Base` class that defines a member of type `IMember` called `Member`. Then I have a `Child` class that inherits `Base` and defines a new member `IMember` called `Member2`.
I serialize an instance of `Child` class, saved in a variable of type `Base` expecting all child and base members to be serialized. Except that while `Member2` from `Child` is serialized, the member with same type defined in the `Base` class is NOT serialized, (or at least when de-serializing I get a null for its value)

My classes are exactly like this:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Member))]
    public interface IMember {
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
        int value { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract()]
    public class Member : IMember {
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract()]
    public class Base  {

        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)] 
        public virtual string Name { get; set; } = "Base";
        
        [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
        public IMember MyMember { get; set; } = null;

    }

    [ProtoContract()]
    public class Child : Base {
        
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
        public override string Name { get; set; } = "Child";

        [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
        public IMember MyMember2 { get; set; } = null;
        
    }
```

The test code is like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        
        Base b = new Child() {
            MyMember =  new Member() { value = 10 },
            MyMember2 = new Member() { value = 20 }
        };

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, b);
        var bytes = stream.ToArray();
        
        stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<Child>(stream);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The de-serialized object `obj` has `Member == null` while `Member2 != null`. Why is that?

Comment: You seem to be trying to set up a dual hierarchy here, with the inheritance on the interface, but you *actually* serializing via the classes (which do *not* define inheritance). Given the choice, class-based inheritance is *much* more reliable here than interface based. My recommendation would frankly be: lose the interface (or at least: don't involve the interface in the serialization). It is a little hard to unpick what you're trying to model here, so I'm struggling to rewrite this as an example. Can you explain the scenario more, perhaps?

Comment: Found the problem... I was missing the [ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Child))] in the base class. Added it and everything works fine :) Thanks @MarcGravell ... After 10 hours programming I could not see that mistake yesterday. But you are right this is quite an abstract example. I am just running some tests on your engine. This wasn't a real scenario. However it actually works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class is missing the [ProtoInclude] attribute to specify the hierarchy.

```
[ProtoContract()]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Child))]
public class Base  {

    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)] 
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = "Base";
    
    [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
    public IMember MyMember { get; set; } = null;

}
```